# How to locate relative file path when using GetFiles() in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, path

I've found a few related questions but they're not working that well. The image name is a modified GUID like `3c6b4a9b-8e88-4c8e-93da-258acd2c964f_0` but the extension isn't known (.jpg, .gif, ..etc). The GUID will be coming from a gridview so it's not a static string. Below is what I have but I'm having a difficult time getting the path to work correctly.

```
    string fileName = `3c6b4a9b-8e88-4c8e-93da-258acd2c964f`;
    DirectoryInfo filePath = new DirectoryInfo(@"/Images");
    MessageBox.Show(filePath.ToString());
    FileInfo[] fileArray = filePath.GetFiles(fileName + "_0.*");
```

Keep getting issues with the directory being invalid. Currently the files are stored on my c: drive.

How can I get the relative path without hardcoding it in? I was using `DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Images"));` <strike>which worked temporarily then started giving this error `System.ArgumentException: Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.` which seems to be from the path having the drive "C:"</strike> This doesn't seem to be a permanent solution once the site is launched though.

The actual path is `C:\Website\Name\Images\3c6b4a9b-8e88-4c8e-93da-258acd2c964f_0.jpg`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've used `filePath` as the first parameter to `GetFiles`, just use the wildcard and invoke the overload of `GetFiles` with one parameter.

```
filePath.GetFiles("_0.*");
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, supposed to be `fileName + "_0.*"` I'll fix the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting `DirectoryInfo` for "C:\Images".

You want to use `Server.MapPath` to get the physical path to the folder that is in your website (which could be anywhere on any drive).

Using the `~` means to start from the root of the running website.

So this should do the trick:

```
string fileName = `3c6b4a9b-8e88-4c8e-93da-258acd2c964f`;
DirectoryInfo filePath = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
FileInfo[] fileArray = filePath.GetFiles(fileName + "_0.*");
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, supposed to be `fileName + "_0.*"` I'll fix the code in my question. It did fix part of the error I was getting. Still having issues with the file path.

Comment: @MuffinMan - updated the answer to reflect the problem - the wrong path was being retrieved. Hope that fixes it.